# Add special carriage return characters using a code snippet in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I would like to create a code snippet that produces a double slash between to marks.

For example I write one that produce

```
//>
   Cursor ready to edit
//_
```

This is useful but i want

```
//>
// Cursor
//_
```

And if I end a line between this two marks I want that the snippet create immediately two more slashes

```
//>
// line terminated with an Enter
// Cursor
//_
```

What I need is something similar to what exist with the 3 slash mark that creates the special commentary blog.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// text terminated with an Enter
    /// Triple slash automatically added
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
```

Is that possible to be created?

Comment: This is about one specific programming tool (Visual Studio), not about programming itself, so it might be off-topic.

Comment: So you want to comment the lines? Why not simply use the existing comment functionality Ctrl+E,C ?

Comment: Is because i create an application that use this commentary chunks, and the idea is that the process of creating this chunks must be the less painful possible, or more natural, just like you write the xml comment bloq. Change that lines after written has the problem that the intellisense is going to interfer and sujest things that i don't want. In summary the characteristic is only to make the process of write a commentary chunk a placer. And by experience if something is not friendly and is not comfortable to use it is lost.

Comment: I now that the commentary bloq /* */ has this builtin behavior, but i'm asking because maybe this is possible using some construction inside of the xml of the snippet and somebody hopefully has face that doubt before and know how to do it.

Comment: @voodoomsr Snippets only support static text and 'variables' that you can replace. It can't support additional logic for when your variable (in this case the comment) includes new lines characters. You're looking at extending visual studio with a plug-in if you want to do something like that.   B.t.w. When commenting on other people's comments please include @name in your comment (where name is the name of the other person) this should make sure the other person gets notified you replied.

Comment: @Stefan, advice taken. I'm going to search if i can make a macro to do that, today i was playing with the Macro IDE, and i'm think that it is maybe possible to do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reached the limits of what snippets can do, you might want to try macros.  Visual Studio includes several text editing macros in the samples to get you started.  Tools -> Macros -> Macros IDE -> Samples -> VSEditor.  For example `NewCommentLine()`.  Copy it to MyMacros and adjust to your needs, and then assign it to a key sequence or toolbar.

Comment: I have been looking exactly that, i was thinking in override the enter hotkey and check if the previous line start with a //, if that is true then i call the NewCommentLine(). Maybe this will slow down the text edition too much, i'm going to test if the code editor maintains his responsiveness.